# Check if the proof is correct

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know if my test is correct, I have to demonstrate that the following sequence is from Cauchy:

$r_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$

I did the following:

Sup. $n>m$

$|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|=\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{m}<\epsilon$ si $m>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Let $m \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ which implies that $|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|<\epsilon$

therefore said sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: Not so perfect. what is m such that $m>\frac 1\epsilon$

Comment: Depends.... What if $\frac 1{\epsilon}$ is larger than all natural numbers?  Have you proven that the natural numbers are not bounded above?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I think you should add the tag proof-verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof has a few mistakes. You do not need to use the concept of $\sup$ at all and you don't need to append a period after "sup". It is readily understood that $\sup$ is an abbreviation for 'supremum' without the period. Also, you cannot just simplify $\mid \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}\mid$ as $ \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n}$. If you want to lose the absolute value signs, you'll need to proceed on a case-by-case basis, but, for this question, you don't need to do that.

To show that $r_n = 1/n$ is Cauchy, you must find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall \epsilon > 0, m, n \geq N, \implies \mid r_n - r_m \mid < \epsilon$. Note that the "challenge" of this proof lies in finding a suitable $N$. In your proof, you are trying to bound $m$ which is not quite right.

If I were you, here's how I would have done this proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N > \frac{2}{\epsilon}$ and suppose $m, n \geq N$. This means that $\mid r_n - r_m \mid$ = $\mid \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m}\mid$ $\stackrel{\triangle ineq.}{\leq}$ $\mid \frac{1}{n}\mid + \mid \frac{1}{m}\mid \leq \frac{2}{N} < \epsilon$ and we are done.

Note that I have suppressed some of the "scratch work" in my proof, you can suppress some more or some less, per your preferences.